# Gradle - how to prevent dependent submodule's tasks from running if dependent task fails?

Tags: gradle

In a multi-module project with modules `mod-a` and `mod-b`, `mod-b` has `mod-a` as a project lib dependency:

```
project(":mod_b") {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':mod_a')
    }
}
```

Both `mod-a` and `mod-b` are configured to publish Maven artifacts (jars) if their tests pass, using the [maven-publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html):

```
// within each module's build.gradle
tasks.withType(AbstractPublishToMaven) {
    dependsOn test
}
```

When I run Gradle with the [`--continue`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:continue_build_on_failure) flag then if tests in `mod-a` fail then no `mod-a` artifacts are published.  However, artifacts are published for `mod-b`.  Why is this and how to I prevent this happening (I wish to continue to use the `--continue` option)?

e.g. this results in publishing of `com.example:mod-b:x.y.z`, when I do not wish it to:

```
./gradlew --continue clean publishToMavenLocal
```

i.e. if there were 3 modules (`mod-a` `-depends-on->` `mod-b` `-depends-on->` `mod-c`), then if only `mod-b`'s tests fail and then only `mod-a` should be published).

Comment: Is it true that b's tests pass but a's do not?

Comment: Yes - I discovered the `buildNeeded` task is what is needed to refer to the successful build and test of dependent projects.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make the publish tasks also depend on the [`buildNeeded`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:multiproject_build_and_test) task.  The `buildNeeded` task builds and tests all other projects that the project in question requires.  Thus if a dependent task fails, `buildNeeded` will be marked as having failed and thus the publish task won't fire.